# openVPN with static ip

Tags: openvpn

Using  https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install to create a VPN

Here is my current scenario :

- server A has static ip : 66.64.64.58 and openVPN server is installed and running.
- server B has static ip : 55.64.64.77 and openVPN client is installed.
- server A is a web server
- server B is also a web server running bounded by static ip 55.64.64.77
- Whenever the OPENVPN client starts on server B, **webserver/server B ip address is lost, and all the web-sites goes down**.

Is there a way to start a openVPN server span across multiple host with static IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When OpenVPN client is started on the web server, the default route for outgoing traffic is changed to point to the OpenVPN tunnel.

After that, when visitors try to connect to the web server, the following happens:

Visitor's browser tries to open TCP connection by sending SYN packet to `55.64.64.77`.

The server replies with SYN/ACK packet, and the response is sent to OpenVPN server at `10.8.0.1`. OpenVPN server translates the source address of the packet to OpenVPN server's public IP address and forwards it to the client.

Visitor's computer then discards this packet, because the SYN/ACK packet comes from wrong IP address.

The conclusion is that one cannot use OpenVPN client with a masquerading OpenVPN server when the OpenVPN client machine is also acting as a web server.